# display aspx in iframe and aspx is displaying pdf

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, iframe

I using an iframe to display an aspx page as follows

```
<a href="#" id="trigger">this link</a>
<div id="dialog" style="display:none">
    <div>
    <iframe frameborder="0"  height="600" width="600" src="Displaypdf.aspx"></iframe>
 </div>
    </div>
```

In the Displaypdf.aspx.cs, I am displaying a pdf as follows. I have a button in the aspx, and on clicking the button the pdf is displayed (in the aspx page which is now an iframe)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FilePath = Server.MapPath("sample.pdf");
    WebClient User = new WebClient();
    Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(FilePath);
    if (FileBuffer != null)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
    }
}
```

this works fine. Now I want to do the same thing at Page_Load
But when i put this code in page load, this does not work.

```
protected void Page_LOad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FilePath = Server.MapPath("sample.pdf");
    WebClient User = new WebClient();
    Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(FilePath);
    if (FileBuffer != null)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
    }
}
```

What happens is, I click and get my iframe, but iframe is blank, because first time mein pdf is not getting rendered. can someone tell me how to fix this problem.

Comment: Do you get any errors? or have you tried adding a breakpoint on the start of the page load? I notice you have a grammar error on the first line which should read protected void Page_Load

Comment: no grammer errors :). typing mistake it was. basically, problem is that when i add it to the page load, the iframe is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code and I think you are missing a couple of things to make it work. I have provided an edited version of your code below which should work OK.

The iframe page (aspx):

```
<head>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
     var $dial1 = ""

function openlink(url, title, width, height) {
    $dial1 = $('<div></div>')
                   .html('<iframe id="frame1" style="border: 0px; " src="' + url + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
                   .dialog({
                       autoOpen: false,
                       modal: true,
                       height: height,
                       width: width,
                       title: title
                   });
    $dial1.dialog('open');

</script>


</head>


    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="This Link" OnClientClick="openlink('Displaypdf.aspx', 'Open', '1000', '470'); return true;" OnClick="Button1_Click" />


        </form>
    </body>
```

Displaypdf.aspx.cs:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string FilePath = Server.MapPath("sample.pdf");
            WebClient User = new WebClient();
            Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(FilePath);
            if (FileBuffer != null)
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
                Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Oh and if you need a button in your iframe, add it to the Displaypdf.aspx and double click to create the event handler. Then take the code from the page load and put it within the button click event.

Comment: thanks connersz for the code. it works fine, But i want the iframe to me a dialog pop-up, not in the same page, how can i do that ?

Comment: @user2256404 I have changed to code. The popup will now open within a jQuery dialog which is a modal window when the button is clicked. When the dialog loads it will show the PDF page which should do the required actions when it loads. Please note: you need to change the two jquery references to a copy of your own or use the hosted versions by jQuery or Google. I have not changed the code so you might need to tinker a little but it should be very close.

Comment: Thanks @connersz, But one more thing, now since the iframe id is inside the jquery function, i cant use it in the .cs file.

Comment: @user2256404 I don't think you need it in the .cs file. The button will create a dynamic iframe inside a jquery modal window. The URL for the iframe will be the Displaypdf.aspx screen and when it loads that page the Page_Load event handler will be hit which loads the PDF details, this will then show inside the modal window. If you change the return inside the button onclientclick to 'return false;' it will do the required action without doing a postback and without running any code on the iframe page.

Comment: okies, I dunno if i am missing something, But now what happens is, the page_Load is hit (of my display pdf page), and the modal window is popped up, But the pdf is not displayed in the modal window, its blank, also, the modal window closes automatically within 2 seconds.

Comment: @user2256404 The modal window might be closing because of the return true, did you try changing it to return false;? If the PDF still doesn't load after that then add some text into DisplayPDF.aspx to check that something loads inside the modal window. If it does then you will have an issue with the PDF function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this worked :) Now just one more thing, By default, the floating pdf options bar is displayed (which has print , save options etc). Is there anyway to hide this? :)

Comment: @user2256404 I'm not that familiar with the PDF options so you would need to explore the properties or start another question. If this has helped you with the original query I would appreciate it if you mark it as the answer.